Does Remix need to be deployed every time code changes are made?
I am writing Solidity code in Remix (creating a VRF with Chainlink) and every time I make changes, I deploy using my subscriptionID, and then call functions under Deployed/Unpinned Contracts. This is a pretty manual workflow and also uses a lot of SepoliaETH (I got free SepoliaETH from different faucets, but ended up paying for some out of pocket because I was using so much).
I am wondering if the aforementioned setup is  the optimal way that people test code changes in Remix? If I have existing Remix code that works and deploys correctly, and want to make some quick changes, such as for example returning 'The random number is' + [randomNumber] rather than just [randomNumber], is there a way I could test these changes quickly without having to go through the whole process I described in paragraph one?

As @Torof suggested, I also recommend you to use Foundry and then create Mock contracts for Chainlink VRF, Price Feeds, etc. Because, that way, you can test in the local environment using the local anvil node without any hassle of getting test ETH from the faucet  and potentially spending them quickly for just a few tests and adjustments..
You can watch this amazing tutorial on Smart Contract Lottery provided by Patrick Collins, and see how he has created Mock contracts in the same.
If you want to learn more about Foundry and the implementation of various cool projects in the same, then you can also explore Cyfrin Updraft.

A smart contract is an object filled with bytecode.
When you deploy it, the bytecode is stored at a specific address on the Blockchain.
You cannot modify the bytecode of a deployed smart contract.
It is indeed a hassle to deploy everytime on testnet (through Remix or else), because if you want to modify your code you have to redeploy the new contract.
There is no other way.
And this why smart contract devs use testing/deploying frameworks such as Foundry or Hardhat.
They have localnets, so that you can easily and quickly redeploy new contracts in a matter of seconds or even write tests and test the modifications you just made without deploying.
Hope that helps and answers your question.

OK, I will try Foundry or Hardhat. I also might use WAGMI or Ethers.js to have the generated random number show up on a sort of front end. Before having the number show up on a front end though, I want to understand how others can see the random number generated in something other than my Remix environment.
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xa3a16deb275c79c7eb6258b76c62af7d2c72922d#writeContract
Under Contract -> Write Contract, I can see the requestRandomWords

sSo would one have to connect a web3 wallet and then click 'Write'?
Because I thought for this transaction, the random number/words were already generated when I deployed with Remix.
Is it possible to see the already generated random number/words through Etherscan?

I don't want to create a new randomly generated number, rather, I want people to be able to see on Etherscan the number that was generated already when I deployed through Remix.

In a smart contract you can do two things: write to the Blockchain and read the Blockchain.
Writing costs gas, reading is free.
A function needs to have the "view" modifier and not write to the Blockchain to be free.
In your case if the random number is already stored, you just need to read it.
Also if our answers are useful to you, please upvote them.
